# Error while overriding public virtual EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a asp.net core 6.0 project ( clean architecture )

My question is related with
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.entry?view=efcore-5.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-entry-1(-0).

`public virtual EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;`

I tried like this But I got error,

Interface.cs

```
 EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>([NotNullAttribute] TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
```

implementation

```
 public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>([NotNullAttribute] TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {

        var entries = ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(e => e.Entity == entity).FirstOrDefault();

        
        var result =  base.Entry(entries);

        // EntityEntry<EntityEntry> result1 = result;
        return result;
    }
```

Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<TEntity>'
```

How can I fixed this?
Please help me.
Thanks

Update:
Answer

```
public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity), "Entity cannot be null.");
        }

        var result = base.Entry(entity);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `entries` is IEnumerable. You are trying to get `Entry` from enumerable.

Comment: You only call `base.Entry`, you may as well remove the override.